# fgetc() does not return '\n' characters

Tags: c

I am trying to read a text file using the FILE* type. Everything is fine, except with the fgetc() function.

In fact, I'd like to check how many '\n' characters are there in the file, but the function never returns that value even though there is one in the file I'm reading. Has someone ever experienced this situation?

The code i'm using is the following:

```cpp
char ch;
while (ch!=EOF) {
    ch = (char) fgetc(gl_file);
    if(ch=='\n') newline_counter++;
}
```

`newline_counter` remains 0.

Comment: `char ch;` ==> `int ch = 0;`. Stop hiding warnings with hard casts.

Comment: Here `char ch;` is not initialised, so `while (ch!=EOF) {` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: to check the value of _ch_ before to assign it has an undefined bahevior

Comment: There's a reason for `fgetc` to return an `int`: `EOF` is -1. Casting it to a `char` makes it to take as end of file if someone puts a 0xff on the file (it's usually the non-breakable space, so it's possible to happend). Don't cast it to char until you don't need to.

Comment: and where is `newline_counter` definition?

Comment: https://ideone.com/ToUqyS seems to work if you do this.

Comment: @yaho I defined it before, this is just a small portion of the code.

Comment: @bruno yeah maybe, this is the first time I use the `FILE*` type, I've always used `fstream` before.

Comment: @Mirko also signedness issues, if `char` is unsigned then it will get into an infinite loop because the comparison will always fail due to unsigned values never being negative and therefore never being `EOF`

Comment: @FFmpegEnthusiast true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't initialize `ch` before checking its value and `ch` is `char` while `fgetc` returns `int`.
Rewrite to something like:

```
int ch;
while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
{
  if(ch == '\n')
    ++newline_counter;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

no need to cast returned value from `fgetc`. use `getc` instead of `fgetc` :

> `getc()` is equivalent to `fgetc()` except that it may be implemented as a macro which evaluates ***stream*** more than once.

```
char ch = getc(fp);
do{
   if (ch == '\n') ++newline_counter;
} while ((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF);
```

or you can use `getline()`:

> `getline()`  reads an entire line from ***stream***.

```
char *ch = NULL;
size_t len = 0;
while (getline(&ch, &len, file) != -1)
    ++line;
```

> If `*ch` is set to `NULL` and `*len` is set `0` before the call, then `getline()` will allocate a buffer for storing the line.

Comment: Did you just ignore the other answers and comments that explain why assigning the result of `getc` to a `char` is a bad idea?